# How to test request/response between 2 micro services with testharnes

Tags: asp.net-core, rabbitmq, automated-tests, integration-testing, masstransit

I have 2 micro services that micro A request data with rabbitmq to micro B and get the response from micro B and works perfect.
How can i write integration tests in micro A for my command that use **IRequestCliect** to get response from micro B without injecting consumer?
I'm using masstransint v8 and rabbitmq.
If give me a sample, I will thank full